# Database Tuning Advisor: Naming of Recommended Indexes and Statistics

Tags: sql-server, database-tuning-advisor

When using the SQL Server Database Tuning Advisor, it generates default names for the objects (indexes, statistics and views) it recommends. Here are a few:

[image]

**These names are horrible.**

Is there an efficient method to assign reasonable names to all those objects? I'd like to apply about 100 recommendations at once, and I don't feel like manually typing a name for each of them.

Here is an example of a "nice" name: `IX_StudyCourses_Name`

Comment: Although the ITW is a great tool for identifying inefficiencies in your database, applying the recommendations blindly 100 at a time without understanding the consequences of each IMO isn't going to solve things. Take the time to understand and design clustering, NC indexes and statistics around your data, taking into consideration reads, writes, index widths etc. Silver bullets are dangerous.

Comment: You are right. I intend to go through all recommendations. I don't apply them blindly. However, the standard for a recommendation applying is very low as the work load is read-only and the database size small.